# Make a function run once by redefining

Tags: javascript, performance

I've found myself using this pattern recently to do initialization that should only ever run once:

```
function myInit() {
  // do some initialization routines
  myInit = function () {return;};
}
```

This way if I had two different methods which required something myInit did, it would ensure that it would only run once. See:

```
function optionA() { myInit(); doA(); }
function optionB() { myInit(); doB(); }
```

In the back of my head I feel like I'm missing something and I shouldn't be doing this.  Is there any reasons why I shouldn't write code like this?

Comment: Have a flag variable globally and call myInit only if the flag is not already set

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any reasons why I shouldn't write code like this?

One reason is that the function will only work as you intend in the scope it was defined in. E.g. if you pass the function somewhere else, it won't be affected by your modifications and in the worst case would create an implicit global variable. E.g.

```
function myInit() {
  // do some initialization routines
  myInit = function () {return;};
}

function foo(init) {
   init();
   init();
}

foo(myInit);
```

The better approach is to encapsulate the whole logic:

```
var myInit = (function() {
    var initialized = false;
    return function() {
        if (initialized) return;
        initialized = true;
        // do some initialization routines
    };
}());
```

Now, no matter how, where and when you call `myInit`, it will do the initialization step only once.

Comment: Assigning a new function to `myInit` could be an additional optimisation pattern though, as it can omit the test for `initialized` from its code. [Here is an example](https://github.com/bergus/F/blob/master/lazy.js#L54) of a combination of both techniques

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something like,

```
var myInitCalled = false; // Global declaration of flag variable

function myInit() {
  // do some initialization routines
  myInitCalled  = true;   // Setting the global variable as true if the method is executed
  myInit = function () {return;};
}
```

Then in your methods, you can probably use:

```
function optionA()
{ 
    if(!myInitCalled  ) // Checking if first time this is called.
    {myInit();}
     doA();
}
function optionB() 
{
   if(!myInitCalled )
   {myInit();}
    doB();
}
```

This will ensure that myInit is called only once!!

Comment: This recursion will block your processing **a lot**. Try using `setTimeout(function, 1)` instead. Or any small value.

Comment: @MarkGabriel: Where do you see any recursion here?

Comment: Oh wait. Sorry. My bad. Read `doA()` as `optionA()` and same for B.